# onTabSelected change Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost

I am trying to change the Fragment `onTabSelected`.

Because at the moment, if you swipe the transitions work fine. But if you click on the `Tab`, the Fragments won't switch. The `Tab` gets highlighted, but the content remains the same.

The issue is with my `onTabSelected` method. I need a suggestion on how to switch to Fragments `onTabSelected`.

Unfortunately I cannot extend my `MainActivity` to `FragmentActivity`, since I won't be able to use `ActionBar` in that case (I am required to extend `ActionBarActivity`).

**onTabSelected snippet:**

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
  int position = tab.getPosition();

  switch (position) {
    case 0:
        break;
    case 1:
        break;
    case 2:
        break;
  }
}
```

**Part of MainActivity that matters here:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;

    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Novice", "Članki", "O Tribuni" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(android.app.ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));

        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });


    }
```

Any help / suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, I figured it out by myself guys.
The answer is to notify the `viewPager` about the *TabSelected*.

Use this line of code in your `onTabSelected`  method:

```
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
```

Hope it helps someone else too!

Comment: It really helped! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an `OnTabSelectedListener` you can implement a `FragmentPagerAdapter` and forward the `ViewPager` events to the `TabLayout`:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
tabLayout.addTab(...);

ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
viewPager.setAdapter(new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, so should work for you:

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition(),true);
    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
}
```

Comment: we posted on the same time, i just figured it out also :) thanks tho!